# Reforming sentences with wollen/sollen in subjektiver Bedeutung?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Formen sie die Sätze um und verwenden Sie "wollen" oder "sollen". Achten sie auf die Zeitform

> Beide Politiker gaben an, diese Tätigkeiten problemlos mit ihrer Überzeugung vereinbaren zu können.
>
> Beide Politiker wollen diese Tätigkeiten problemlos mit ihrer Überzeugung vereinbaren können.

In the reformulation, why did the "zu" go away?

Answer (score 1):

Because those sentences are related but not equivalent to each other. The *zu* was introduced by the infinitive clause to begin with.

> Beide Politiker gaben an, diese Tätigkeiten problemlos mit ihrer Überzeugung vereinbaren zu können.
>
> Beide Politiker gaben an, dass sie diese Tätigkeiten problemlos mit ihrer Überzeugung vereinbaren können.

Those two sentences are equivalent.

Now you should phrase a new sentence with a modal. Modals want a plain infinitive, not a zu-infinitive.

> Beide Politiker sollen/wollen diese Tätigkeiten problemlos mit ihrer Überzeugung vereinbaren können.